# "RA layer request failed" error with Subclipse, no errors with web browser

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using STS 2.8.1 (I think it's based on Eclipse Indigo) with Subclipse 1.6.18.

I'm trying to check some code out from a repository, but when I add the repository location, I get the following error:

> RA layer request failed
>   svn: Server sent unexpected return value (503 Service Unavailable) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://a.b.com:18080/svn/myproject'

The thing is, if I try to access that repository from a web browser (e.g. Chrome or IE), I'm allowed to access it. It asks for my username and password, and after I enter them, I can see the project tree.

Does anyone know why I can access from the web browser but not from STS?

The proxy settings are configured correctly for Subclipse (and I can access other repositories from STS, but not that one).

Comment: double check the proxy password: it could be a case where the the svn settings (`c:\Documents and Settings\_username_\Application Data\Subversion\servers` or `~/.subversion/servers`) might overwrite the Eclipse settings

Comment: I already did, and they're correct. And as I said, I'm able to connect to other repository locations, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any other ideas? thanks for your help!

Comment: Correct, both for Eclipse and for svn? Also try a fresh Eclipse installation (in another directory that your current Eclipse) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I'll try to do that... but I don't know why, if Eclipse is the problem, it would connect to other repositories and not this exact one :(

Comment: i solved it, adding the corresponding exception in the servers file, like this: http-proxy-exceptions = exception.com

Comment: Excellent. I have posted an answer documenting a bit your particular setting.

Answer (score 7):

This is usually due to an SVN setting  (`c:\Documents and Settings\_username_\Application Data\Subversion\servers` or `~/.subversion/servers`) overriding an Eclipse setting.

Or one of those settings could have the wrong password for the proxy.

However, the [OP Neets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629868/neets) reports:

> - I'm able to connect to other repository locations (so the proxy password is correct)
> - I solved it, adding the corresponding exception in the servers file, like this:

```
http-proxy-exceptions = exception.com
```

That is compliant with what describes the openDNS article [Configuring Subversion to Use a Proxy Server](https://docs.opends.org/wiki/page/ConfiguringSubversionToUseAProxyServer?version=2):

```
http-proxy-exceptions
```

> This specifies a set of repository addresses for which you don't need to access a proxy server. For example, if you have a repository on your local LAN, then you probably won't need a proxy to access it.
>   This should be a comma-delimited list of servers, and you can use an asterisk as a wildcard.
>   If all of the repositories that you will access require you to use a proxy server, then you can leave this out.
>
> The following shows a sample configuration that will use a proxy server to access all servers outside of the example.com domain:

```
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = *.example.com
http-proxy-host = proxy.example.com
http-proxy-port = 8080
http-proxy-username = myuserid
http-proxy-password = mypassword
```

Comment: Note: [Jabda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1260393/jabda) mentioned in [a deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527431/6309) having seen that error because the username for the repository was case sensitive in Eclipse. Typing in the exact correct username solved the issue.