# Subclipse and Eclipse - RA layer request failed

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I'm following the instructions for installing Ardor3D as an Eclipse Project Set via Subclipse; instructions at:

http://www.ardor3d.com/wiki/svneclipsetutorial

I installed Subclipse from

http://subclipse.tigris.org/

and installed fine. If I go to Eclipse's Preferences and Team|SVN I can see that the SVN Interface Client is JavaHL, and hence installed fine.

However, when I come to checkout the code at:

http://ardorlabs.svn.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1

by selecting New|Other|SVN|Check Projects from SVN I get the following error message:

RA layer request failed
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://ardorlabs.svn.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1'
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://ardorlabs.svn.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1': could not connect to server (http://ardorlabs.svn.cvsdude.com)

I know the URL is valid as I can install the above fine on my work m/c of WinXP. However, the same installation on my personal laptop of Win7 fails to connect.

I tried temporarily disabling the firewall and it still fails.

I've tried playing around with the config and server files in:

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Subversion

but to be honest not 100% sure as what to change, if anything as I'm not using proxy settings.

If there's an expert out there who's knows the solution to this problem I would greatly appreciate hearing from you.

Thanks

Graham

PS. I find the error message "RA layer request failed" confusing as the URL is valid.

Comment: Please see if http://stackoverflow.com/q/8983845/1321873 is helpful

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem, which turned out to be caused by a proxy server. The solution to my problem was to configure subversion to work with the proxy server, however it was not obvious how to do this.

You should have a directory similar to : `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\Subversion`

In that directory there will be a file called `servers`.

I un-commented and edited the following entries and my subversion is now working fine with Eclipse:

```
http-proxy-host
http-proxy-port
http-proxy-username
http-proxy-password
```

Why exactly you can't configure this through Eclipse is abit of a mystery, but there you go.

Comment: Under Win 7, this path will be
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`

Comment: On my Win 7 enterprise edition the location was :                                   `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming`

Answer (score 4):

Another user account could login, I got the error as described above. The difference was the Proxy setting which was missing in my account. It is stored per user in the Registry and I could easily change this in the Tortoise SVN config.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error with our server.  While we were able to successfully access the CollabNet 5 SVN admin console, navigating to the repository to browse it from the admin console would fail.  We also were not able to connect from Subclipse clients.

The problem turned out we were not hitting the correct port on the server.  We had reconfigured the default port from 80 to 4343 and the admin console reported the changed setting but the server was still running on 80.

For what it's worth, in order for the configuration change to stick, we had to bring the repo server down and make the change in the admin console and then restart the machine.  We were then able to browse the repo from the link in the admin console.