# How do I configure Subclipse to use a "Dynamic Proxy"?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I've been getting "RA Layer Request Failed" whenever I try connecting to my subversion location. Accessing them through my IE browser gives me no problem at all.

This isn't a duplicate of this question:
["RA layer request failed" error with Subclipse, no errors with web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983845/ra-layer-request-failed-error-with-subclipse-no-errors-with-web-browser)

It says there that I have to edit the file:
c:\Documents and Settings_username_\Application Data\Subversion\servers or ~/.subversion/servers

But that is only applicable if the host name and port number are both given. But **we're using a dynamic proxy**, that is, **host name and port are not given** hence dynamic. To give you an idea how our proxy settings are configured, in my IE8, Tools -> Internet Options -> LAN Settings dialogue box, the "**Automatic detect settings**" and "**Use automatic configuration script**" are both ticked. And the URL to "Address" field is filled in. I think this configuration is called "Dynamic Proxy" where the info about your proxy is automatically detected.

**How do I tell subclipse to do the same thing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt Subversion has the functionality to operate correctly in such an environment. I think the best you can do is read this article http://techblog.mirabito.net.au/?p=21 , then get hold of the proxy PAC file, and work out by inspection, the correct (static) proxy settings to use.

Comment: it would be nice to have a citation though

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/libproxy/ indicates that most apps don't support PAC. So if Subversion was rebuilt with libproxy, maybe you could use `http_proxy=pac+http://bla` syntax.